# are assembly bindings ignored for PublicKeyToken=null?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following in my `app.config`.

```xml
<configuration>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="bin2" />
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Foo" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="null">
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.4497.27619" />
      </assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
  ...
<configuration>
```

Fusion logging tells me that it's not looking in `bin2` for my assembly.

*LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL* (and it never searches in `bin/Debug/bin2/Foo`)

Is this a problem with not having a `publicKeyToken`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, they are ignored for assemblies that are not strong named (have a publicKeyToken) since the CLR ignores version numbers for these assemblies.

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx) for more information.

Comment: The specific note on the page says: "You cannot redirect versions for assemblies that are not strong-named. The common language runtime ignores the version for assemblies that are not strong-named."

Comment: @JJS: For .NET 4.5 that note does not exist. It is not clear, though, whether the behaviour has changed.